# (In)correct use of a linear time trend variable, and most efficient fix?

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, forecasting

I have 3133 rows representing payments made on some of the 5296 days between 7/1/2000 and 12/31/2014; that is, the "Date" feature is non-continuous:

```
> head(d_exp_0014)
  Year Month Day    Amount Count     myDate
1 2000     7   6  792078.6     9 2000-07-06
2 2000     7   7  140065.5     9 2000-07-07
3 2000     7  11  190553.2     9 2000-07-11
4 2000     7  12  119208.6     9 2000-07-12
5 2000     7  16 1068156.3     9 2000-07-16
6 2000     7  17       0.0     9 2000-07-17
```

I would like to fit a linear time trend variable,

`t <- 1:3133`

to a linear model explaining the variation in the Amount of the expenditure.

`fit_t <- lm(Amount ~ t + Count, d_exp_0014)`

However, this is obviously wrong, as t increments in different amounts between the dates:

```
> head(exp)
  Year Month Day    Amount Count       Date t
1 2000     7   6  792078.6     9 2000-07-06 1
2 2000     7   7  140065.5     9 2000-07-07 2
3 2000     7  11  190553.2     9 2000-07-11 3
4 2000     7  12  119208.6     9 2000-07-12 4
5 2000     7  16 1068156.3     9 2000-07-16 5
6 2000     7  17       0.0     9 2000-07-17 6
```

Which to me is the exact opposite of a linear trend.

What is the most efficient way to get this data.frame merged to a continuous date-index?  Will a date vector like

`CTS_date_V <- as.data.frame(seq(as.Date("2000/07/01"), as.Date("2014/12/31"), "days"), colnames = "Date")`

yield different results?

I'm open to any packages (using fpp, forecast, timeSeries, xts, ts, as of right now); just looking for a good answer to deploy in functional form, since these payments are going to be updated every week and I'd like to automate the append to this data.frame.

Comment: Without knowing much about your statistical model, Why not just use the `Date` variable in your model? Dates are just numerical values in R underneath it all.

Comment: @thelatemail There's not too much to know - just doing a budget forecast, which in the end will take number of historical contracts by month, their types (there are 5), the mix of those types, the region within which the contract is executed (also five categories), and the total historical spend by month and predict the amount of payments in a given month, 24 months forward.  There is a "causal" component to this later on, but obviously those specifications and interpretations will be very different.

Comment: @thelatemail I guess I'm wondering if using a date vector like `CTS_date_V <- as.data.frame(seq(as.Date("2000/07/01"), as.Date("2014/12/31"), "days"), colnames = "Date")
` will yield different results.

Comment: You already have a date column, you don't need to create another one (`t`, or an every day sequence). Just use the one you have.

Comment: @Gregor so it's not an issue that they are at irregular intervals?

Comment: Dates are stored as a number of days since some origin, so it will be just fine. It only becomes an issue if you create a new column `1:nrow()` that assumes they're regularly spaced. You should read `?Date`, and take a look at `as.numeric(yourdata$Date)`---which is how they'll be treated by most models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think some kind of transformation to regular (continuous) time series is a good idea.
You can use `xts` to transform time series data (it is handy, because it can be used in other packages as regular ts)

### Filling the gaps

```
# convert myDate to POSIXct if necessary
# create xts from data frame x 
ts1 <- xts(data.frame(a = x$Amount, c = x$Count), x$myDate )
ts1

# create empty time series
ts_empty <- seq( from = start(ts1), to = end(ts1), by = "DSTday")

# merge the empty ts to the data and fill the gap with 0
ts2 <- merge( ts1, ts_empty, fill = 0)

# or interpolate, for example:
ts2 <- merge( ts1, ts_empty, fill = NA)
ts2 <- na.locf(ts2)

# zoo-xts ready functions are:
#     na.locf - constant previous value
#     na.approx - linear approximation
#     na.spline - cubic spline interpolation
```

### Deduplicate dates

In your sample there is now sign of duplicated values. But based on a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28618719/having-a-lot-of-issues-with-time-series-objects-in-r) it is very likely. I think you want to aggregate values with `sum` function:

```
ts1 <- period.apply( ts1, endpoints(ts1,'days'), sum)
```

Comment: `Error in xts(data.frame(a = exp$Amount, c = exp$Count), exp$myDate) : 
  order.by requires an appropriate time-based object`

Comment: Use `as.POSIXct(exp$myDate)`

Comment: `Error in as.POSIXct.default(exp$myDate) : 
  do not know how to convert 'exp$myDate' to class “POSIXct”`

Comment: If it is not in ISO format yyyy-mm-dd (like in your question), you can specify format in the function- for example: `as.POSIXct("20000706", format = "%Y%m%d")` or exp$myDate is not a date...

Comment: any clue why forecast's seasonplot() and stats's stl() functions are saying `Error in seasonplot(ts1) : Frequency must be > 1` and `Error in stl(ts1, s.window = 5) : 
  series is not periodic or has less than two periods` respectively? (I dropped the c column because these methods need a univariate series.)

Comment: Set frequency attribute - for example: `attr(ts1, "frequency") <- 7`

Comment: not trying to be difficult here but it's still throwing those same errors (ie saying frequency must be > 1).  I've also tried setting that attribute with `attr(ts1,"frequency") <- as.integer(7)`, as well, since `str(ts1)` showed that attribute type to be `num 7`

Comment: try `stl(ts1, s.window="periodic")`

Comment: still same error. if i check `periodicity(ts1)` it says `0 seconds periodicity from 2000-07-01 to 2014-12-31` trying to.period

Comment: I don't think I am able to reproduce this situation. Could you define it in a new question?

Comment: Could you try this and see if it helps at all? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28615940/testing-forecasts-in-r-data-w-date-irregularities